# Pass Record ID Between LWC's

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a LWC that has a list of records.  Here is the list:

```
<template for:each={opps} for:item="opp">
    <tr key={opp.Id}>
      <td><div onclick={getSelectedOpp} data-oppid={opp.Id}><a >{opp.Name}</a></div></td>
      <td>{opp.StageName}</td> 
      <td>{opp.CloseDate}</td>
      <td>{opp.Amount}</td> 
      <td><div><lightning-button label="Edit Opp" data-oppid={opp.Id} onclick={EditOpp}></lightning-button></div></td>
     </tr>
  </template>
```

I am trying to pass the opp.id in the method to the new page.  I was able to get a hardcoded Id to work, just can't figure out how to use the specific record id instead.  Here is my button funcion:

```
      // Navigation to Opp Detail Component
    EditOpp(evt) {
        let oppId = evt.target.dataset.oppid;
        
 
        console.log('!!! z' + oppId);
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: "standard__component",
            attributes: {
                componentName: "c__oppWizardPortalWrapper",
                
            },
            state: {
                //c__recordId: '006W000000H2PTpIAN'
                c__recordId: oppid
            }
        });
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the opportunity id into data attribute of the button like below.

```
<td><div><lightning-button data-oppid={opp.Id}  label="Edit Opp" onclick={EditOpp}></lightning-button></div></td>
```

Now you can easily get that id in the button on click method like below.

```
EditOpp(event) {
     let oppId = event.target.dataset.oppid;
     // pass oppId to the navigation mixin
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have achieved

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-text-link" onclick={editIO} data-value={ioObj.Id}>
    Edit
</a>
```

JS:

```
editIO(event) {
  let selectedId = event.currentTarget.dataset.value;
}
```